# css adjusting width depending on elements

Tags: css

i am devloping a navigation menu

[image]

If you see the image,there is some space left at the right,
how can i automatic adjust the space there.

The no of elements there aren't fixed..They can be 2,3 ,4 or something

[currently there are 4]

Comment: Do you want your navigation bar to take up the entire container?

Comment: yes
but the no of submenus in navigation bar change,The can be either 2,3 4,6,10

at present they are 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be to have your horizontal nav bar behave as a table by using `display: table` on your `ul`; and `display: table-cell` on your `li`.

I would be able to give you some better instructions if you posted some code; but here's an example:

```
    nav { 
        width: 500px; /* This would be set to the width of the existing container */
    }

    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        display: table;
        width: 100%; 
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    nav a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Your `.menu-item` has a set `width `&  `float: left` property. That's why it's not working. Remove both of these and it'll work.